# Did set isn't observing model property's change - Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsdictionary, didset

Hey I'm using a didSet to set an Array of keys from a dictionary so that I can avoid replication when I try to access the array to populate collection view cells. The didSet is supposed to occur when a Cafe object gets changed but when it isn't.

```
private var _hashArray: [String]?

var hashArray: [String]? {
    return _hashArray
}

var cafe: Cafe? {
    didSet{
        if let hashCounts = cafe?.hashtagCounts {
            _hashArray = Array(hashCounts.keys)
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
RatingService.retrieveForCafe(yelpID: (cafe?.id)! , completion: { (tags) in
            self.cafe?.hashtagCounts = tags
            self.hashtagCollectionView.reloadData()

        })
    }
    else {
        print("is nil")
    }
```

when I print out tag, it prints out the dictionary with its key and value correctly but when I try printing out hashArray or _hashArray, it's nil. Can you let me know where I did incorrectly? Thanks

Comment: Is `Cafe` a struct or a class?

Comment: Cafe is a class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Property observers are not called when the property of a class is changed. This is because classes are *reference types* and even though a property of it may change, a new object is not allocated and so the property observer is not triggered.

Structs, however, are *value types* and so changing a property of a struct causes a new object to be allocated to store it. This new object is assigned to replace the current one so the property observer sees this change and fires. If you initialize a struct with `let` instead of `var` you'll notice that you can't change any properties of it with the dot notation. This is because changing a single property "changes" the entire object (a new one is created).

Therefore, change `Cafe` to a struct instead of a class and the property observer should be triggered when `hashtagCounts` is changed.